# where should I declare Global variable in sugarcrm

Tags: global-variables, sugarcrm

where should I declare a Global variable in sugarcrm so that I can access it from anywhere in sugarcrm application? Should I declare it in index.php or config.php or any other place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

config_override.php is the best location for custom config values. This file is placed in the root folder.

Set new value with:

```
$sugar_config['my_variable']
```

Retrieve value with:

```
$GLOBALS['sugar_config']['my_variable']
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work in sugarcrm multithreading. if i set "my_variable" to 1 , in an "after_relationship_add" logic hook and in the middle of that logic_hook, i receive an entrypoint GET call from another system and check the "my_variable", i still get 0 because the "after_relationship_add" logic hook did not finish yet.